# Using the Mercator series for $\log(1+\frac{1}{k})$, show that $\frac{1}{k}-\log(k+1)+\log(k)=\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{1}{3k^3}+\frac{1}{4k^4}-...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What I have done so far is this:

Mercator series for $\log(1+\frac{1}{k})=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{3k^3}-\frac{1}{4k^4}+...$

first I multiplied both sides by $-1$ to obtain:

$-\log(1+\frac{1}{k})=-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{1}{3k^3}+\frac{1}{4k^4}-...$

Then I added $\frac{1}{k}$ to both sides

$\frac{1}{k}-\log(1+\frac{1}{k})=-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{1}{3k^3}+\frac{1}{4k^4}-...+\frac{1}{k}$

which gives

$\frac{1}{k}-\log(1+\frac{1}{k})=\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{1}{3k^3}+\frac{1}{4k^4}-...$

I don't have a lot of experience with series manipulation. But I think I'm doing this incorrectly since I still have $log(k)$ unaccounted for. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You need some experience with log manipulation. $1+{1\over k}={1+k \over k}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer and what I do with it

Comment: Oh, now I see $log(1+\frac{1}{k})$ can be written as $log(\frac{1+k}{k})$ and then can be written as $log(1+k) - log(k)$

Answer (score 1):

Mercator series for $\log(1+\frac{1}{k})=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{3k^3}-\frac{1}{4k^4}+...$

first bring $\frac{1}{k}$ to the other side to obtain:

$-\frac{1}{k}+\log(1+\frac{1}{k})=-\frac{1}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{3k^3}-\frac{1}{4k^4}+...$

Then I rewrote $log(1+\frac{1}{k})$ as $log(\frac{k+1}{k})$ and then using log rules we get $log(1+k)-log(k)$ to obtain

$-\frac{1}{k}+log(1+k)-log(k)=-\frac{1}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{3k^3}-\frac{1}{4k^4}+...$

and finally multiply both sides by $-1$ to get the final answer

$\frac{1}{k}-log(1+k)+log(k)=+\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{1}{3k^3}+\frac{1}{4k^4}-...$